# Apache proxy returns 502 with AH00898: Error reading from remote server

Tags: apache2, mod-proxy, proxypass

everyone.

I'm doing a practice task to create redirect for one location using load balancer, but I cant figure out why this isnt works (getting 502). I've tried setting several env-vars and settings like ProxyPreserveHost and alike, so far nothing.

Config:

```
 <VirtualHost *:8080>
        ServerName www.lnxa.nip.io
        ServerAlias *.lnxa.nip.io
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        DirectoryIndex index.nginx-debian.html
        LogLevel debug
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/xip.access.log logz
        Alias "/rbm_images" "/var/www/rebrain/images/"
        <Proxy balancer://rebrain>
                BalancerMember http://example.com:443
        </Proxy>
        <Location />
                Order deny,allow
                Deny from 10.10.10.10
                Allow from all
                AuthType Basic
                AuthName "Restricted Content"
                AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
                Require valid-user
        </Location>
        <Location "/example">
                ProxyPass balancer://rebrain
                ProxyPassReverse balancer://rebrain
        </Location>


</VirtualHost>
```

In error.log there are these errors:

```
AH01102: error reading status line from remote server example.com:443
AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /example
```

Please advise what else can I do.